# Can Lubuntu's "lxsession-edit" (Desktop Session Settings) add new programs at startup or just remove them?

Tags: lubuntu, startup, startup-applications, lxsession

It looks like the second is true, but I want to be sure. I would find it odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly as it seems, this application cannot add, but only remove startup programs.